# How to make a command for a composed symbol to work with all font sizes?

Tags: fonts, symbols, font-metrics

In my paper I need a letter $\mathbb{R}$ with a small circle above it.
Currently I'm using the following command:
`\newcommand{\obbR}{{\mbox{\kern1.4pt \raisebox{7pt} {\scriptsize$\circ$} \kern-9.1pt}\mathbb{R}}}`
But unfortunately it works only with standard font size. The question is how to make a command for this "composed letter", which works with all font sizes.

Actually, I have two problems with writing of this "universal" command.
1. I don't know, how can one make values font-dependent.
2. I don't know, how can one make the small circle, I should put above R, smaller, than `\scriptsize\circ`.

Comment: One thing that you asked about which wasn't answered is your question 1. I think the problem is that you're specifying lengths and sizes it terms of `pt`. Maybe if you use `em` units your commands will scale with the current font context. Can somebody answer this part of his question directly? I think it's interesting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `\mathring` accent. `$\mathring{\mathbb{R}}$` should do what you want.

Comment: Also have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol for how to easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: Thank you, Willie Wong, it works. I will use it. The only problem I see is that this ring, produced with `\mathring` seems to be a bit too small. But, I believe, it's ok.

Thank you, Caramdir, there are useful links there.