# How do I use a circle as a math accent (larger than \mathring)?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, positioning

To denote the interior of a set, I'd like to have a command `\interior`. Now, as one can learn from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2458/how-to-make-a-command-for-a-composed-symbol-to-work-with-all-font-sizes) post, one possibility is to use `\mathring`. This is a neat command, but it produces a circle that to my taste is too small for the purpose. Of course one can experiment with `\overset{\circ}{...}`, but this way I had difficulties getting satisfactory vertical and in particular horizontal positioning of the `\circ`. An example:

```
$\mathring{I}\ \mathring{J}\ \overset{\circ}{I}\ \overset{\circ}{J}$
```

yields [image] .

If one has a close look then one sees that the `\circ` over the `J` should be moved to the right *more* than the `\circ` over the `J`! Is there a way to obtain the same nice automatic positioning as with mathring?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use `\accentset` from the `accents` package:

```
$ \mathring{I}\ \mathring{J}\ \accentset{\circ}{I}\ \accentset{\circ}{J} $
```

[image: example]

Comment: Great, this is what I've always wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

In the end I'm using an even larger circle than in Caramdir's great answer: `accents` sets the `\circ` in `\scriptscriptstyle`; I'm using `\scriptstyle`.
To not affect the line spacing so much, I have the circle lowered and let it stick out a bit of the bounding box of the resulting accented character. (In print it looks nicer than on screen ...)

[image: comparison of different circles]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,accents}
\newcommand{\interior}[1]{\accentset{\smash{\raisebox{-0.12ex}{$\scriptstyle\circ$}}}{#1}\rule{0pt}{2.3ex}}
\fboxrule0.0001pt \fboxsep0pt
\begin{document}
$\mathring{I}\ \accentset{\circ}{I}\ \interior{I}$ \fbox{$\interior{I}$}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is also the Unicode combining character U+030A ◌̊  "COMBINING RING ABOVE":

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(diacritic)#Overring

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! For your answer to be complete, you should add an example of use of that character in LaTeX.