# How to make a command for a circled letter to work with all font sizes?

Tags: symbols, fontsize, math-operators, circles

I introduced the following macros

```
\newcommand{\malcev}{\mathop{\text{\textcircled{\scriptsize M}}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\imalcev}{\mathop{\text{\textcircled{\tiny M}}}\nolimits}
```

The code

```
\[
  \mathbf{V} \malcev \mathbf{W}  \qquad  F_{\mathbf{V} \imalcev \mathbf{W}} \qquad S^{\mathbf{V} \imalcev \mathbf{W}} 
\]
```

now produces an acceptable result

[image: Malcev example]

However, it is certainly not a clean solution since I have to manually switch between \malcev and \imalcev depending on the font size (not to speak about a possible double superscript). I am looking for a better solution (if possible avoiding tikz).
I looked at the following questions

1. [Good way to make \textcircled
   numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers)
2. [How do I put a circle around an
   operator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53698/how-do-i-put-a-circle-around-an-operator/135489#135489)
3. [How to make a command for a composed symbol to work with all font
   sizes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2458/how-to-make-a-command-for-a-composed-symbol-to-work-with-all-font-sizes)

which are certainly relevant, but I was not able to get exactly what I wanted from their answers. One of the difficulties is that I use \textcircled on a scriptsized letter (otherwise my symbol would be too big), but this is probably not a good idea.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: An alternative, arguably cleaner, and in any case shorter solution is offered by John Kormylo on this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290956/65 .  This relies on amsmath's `\text`, extract the actual height of a letter, and draws the operator in proportion to it.

Comment: @michaël This solution is nice, but it relies on tikz.

Comment: Not really; the symbol is drawn with TikZ, but it could be a simple `textcircled`.  For instance: `\newlength\oneex\def\malcev{\mathop{\text{\settoheight{\oneex}{x}\raisebox{0.3\oneex}{\resizebox{!}{\oneex}{\normalsize\textcircled{\scriptsize M}}}}}}`.  Basically, the circled M is written in a "normal" size, and it is then scaled to the height of an x.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case using directly `\mathchoice` seems preferable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fix-cm} % make font arbitrarily scalable
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\malcev}{\mathbin{
  \mathchoice
    {\mbox{\normalsize\textcircled{\scriptsize M}}}
    {\mbox{\normalsize\textcircled{\scriptsize M}}}
    {\mbox{\scriptsize\textcircled{\tiny M}}}
    {\mbox{\tiny\textcircled{\fontsize{3.5}{3.5}\selectfont M}}}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathbf{V} \malcev \mathbf{W}  \qquad
F_{\mathbf{V} \malcev \mathbf{W}} \qquad
S^{\mathbf{V} \malcev \mathbf{W}^{\malcev}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]