# Scale a TikZ picture according to current font in math mode

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode

I want to define a simple shape and use it as a binary math operator.  This implies that it should scale when used as a subscript (e.g., the same behavior as `\bigcirc`).  My attempts so far led me here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\myop}{%
  \mathbin{\text{\tikz \node[circle,draw=black,scale=0.4] () {$r$};}}}

\begin{document}
$A \bigcirc B$ $_{A \bigcirc B}$

$A \myop B$ $_{A \myop B}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Tikz circ]

As one can see, the TikZ variant doesn't behave well: in the first case, the shape is smaller than the operands, while it is pretty much of the same height in the second one.  Removing the `scale`, adding some `minimum size=0mm,inner sep=0mm`, etc. did not change anything to the problem.  Hence:

**Question:**  How can I obtain a smooth scaling of the operator?

Comment: Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160764/4778

Comment: `\text` is basically doing the `mathchoice` here.  I'm really searching for an option that *keeps* the tikz (because I may have something more complex) and that *avoids* a `mathchoice`.  In a way, I'd like to be able to say "Let $x$ be the height of an "o" in the current mode, then scale the tikz picture to $x$."

Comment: comment to @JohnKormylo's comment: one needs to take care of timing of evaluation.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: As Symbol says, it's not that easy, and `\text` goes a long way to make it easier.  However, experiment with `\DeclareRobustCommand{\myop}{\mathbin{\text{\rule{1mm}{.7em}}}}` or similar, and you'll see that it does not scale properly.  What I'd really like to have, again, is something like "Put 'A' in a vbox, and scale the symbol to the height of that vbox."  I just can't seem to be able to do that, because of evaluation timing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `inner sep` and `line width` do not change with the font.  The solution is to define a length that **does** change proportionately with the font.  I chose the height of `\mathstrut`, but almost anything will do.  Also, by drawing the circle separately, you can adjust its size and the size of the contents (`$r$`) separately.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\tempdima}

\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\myop}{%
  \mathbin{\text{\settoheight{\tempdima}{\mathstrut}\raisebox{-.3\tempdima}{%
    \tikz{\draw[line width=0.05\tempdima] circle (0.6\tempdima);
    \node[scale=0.8] {$r$};}}}}}

\begin{document}
$A \bigcirc B$ $_{A \bigcirc B}$

$A \myop B$ $_{A \myop B}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah!  That's perfect!  We arrived at a similar solution at the same time—but I had to search for hours :-)  I used a `resizebox` to avoid having `\tempdima` everywhere, but I'm not sure one is better than the other.  Thanks greatly!