# Correctly scale and space TikZ symbol in math mode

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, symbols

I wish to define a mathematical symbol, similar to `\odot`, using TikZ. The symbol should thus scale appropriately in accordance with its context (e.g. inline math, footnotes, diagrams, etc.). As a template, I followed [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290956). However, it doesn't appear to be scaling correctly in all contexts. Furthermore, the spacing around the symbol is subtly wrong.

Here is a minimal working example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newlength{\oh}

\newcommand{\ostar}{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\text{\settoheight{\oh}{$\odot$}\tikz[baseline=.45\oh]{\draw[line width=.06\oh](0,0)circle[radius=.57\oh]node[overlay,yshift=-.025\oh]{\ensuremath{*}};}}}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    f \odot g \\
    f \ostar g \\
    x^{f \odot g} \\
    x^{f \ostar g} \\
\end{align*}
\vspace{-7ex}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large,row sep=tiny]
    \cdot & \cdot \\
        \cdot & \cdot \\
    \arrow["{f \odot g}"{description}, from=1-1, to=1-2]
        \arrow["{f \ostar g}"{description}, from=2-1, to=2-2]
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: \ostar in various contexts]

As seen in the image, the size of `\ostar` is correct for normal size math and in the commutative diagram. However, it is too large in the superscript (with respect to `\odot`), even though it should be scaled proportionally to `\odot` (since all the dimensions are with respect to `\oh`). Furthermore, though it is a little hard to see in the image, there is less spacing around `\ostar` than around `\odot` in every place it is used.

I suspect there's a simple solution, but I haven't been able to figure it out. How can I fix the definition of `\ostar` so that it behaves the same as `\odot`?

(Note that I actually want to define more complicated symbols than `\ostar` using the same method, so alternative solutions like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451786/how-do-i-put-a-circle-around-a-symbol) do not suffice for my purposes.)

Comment: You should use `\text{$\vcenter{...}$}` in order to fix the size. But this won't work in `tikzcd`, because you're nesting `tikzpicture` inside `tikzpicture`.

Comment: @egreg: that's already a significant improvement, thank you. The spacing appears not to be perfect in `tikzcd`, but it is perhaps close enough to be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the symbol in a `savebox` and use the `scalerel` package to give it the same size as `\odot`. Changing the `inner sep` of the node will make the `*` larger or smaller.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newsavebox{\circstar}
\sbox{\circstar}{\kern.075em\tikz{\node[draw, circle, line width=.36pt, inner sep=.5pt]{$*$};}\kern.075em}

\newcommand{\ostar}{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\usebox{\circstar}}{\odot}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    f \odot g \\
    f \ostar g \\
    x^{f \odot g} \\
    x^{f \ostar g} \\
\end{align*}
\vspace{-7ex}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large,row sep=tiny]
    \cdot & \cdot \\
        \cdot & \cdot \\
    \arrow["{f \odot g}"{description}, from=1-1, to=1-2]
        \arrow["{f \ostar g}"{description}, from=2-1, to=2-2]
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a cleaner solution.